# Does AWS Cognito remove the need for a 'users' table in my database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

With AWS Cognito doing its thing with authentication does this mean I no longer need a traditional 'users' table in my database?

Currently the app I have inherited has the traditional 'users' table I reference with sql queries looking for many-to-many and many-to-one joins with organisation, message boards, etc tables.

Do I query the Cognito user groups (that feels wrong) or is there some 'sync' method to have an updated 'users' table in my database.

Reading to docs and watching a few tutorials is great but no one seams to do more than authenticate. Where is the authorisation, and getting user names, email with join queries.

Be gentle, trying to work and study with a new baby in the room

Answer (score 53, accepted):

My experience has been it does not obsolete the need for a users table, for a couple of reasons.

1. I would routinely run into AWS throttling errors when invoking the Cognito getUser/listUser methods while using Cognito as the primary user data store. AWS support would increase the API limits on our account but I was always worried they would reappear.
2. You are essentially limited to querying users by username/email/phone. The listUser method is very limited for searching
3. If you want to store other user data then you have to put them in custom Cognito attributes and managing those got tiresome quickly

The design I ended up on was to set a post-confirmation trigger on the Cognito user pool and have it copy all the user data into a relational database or DynamoDB when a user signed up. The primary key of the users table would be the Cognito username so if necessary I could lookup the user in both the database and Cognito. Basically I just use Cognito for authentication and not as a primary user database

Comment: Many thanks Brian, thats the path I wanted to take - the best takeaway from your answer is the "post-confirmation trigger".

Comment: How does this work if a user changes an attribute? I didn't see a lambda trigger for attribute updates.

Comment: Correct, there is no update user trigger on Cognito and that is annoying. We ended up just using Cognito for basic authentication and authorization and keeping all user profile data in RDS/Dynamo

Comment: If post confirmation trigger failed multiple times cognito will retry up to 3 times but in case maybe the database is down and all retires have failed, how do you keep the database consistent with cognito?

Comment: @AhmadNabil You would have to handle that scenario yourself. There are a variety of things you could do like have the post confirmation trigger submit to SQS and pick up handling it from there, or if trigger fails 3 times setup a lambda DLQ and reprocess the events that way

Comment: @BrianWinant First option using SQS is good but if the database is down the user would be still able to sign in using cognito even though the message is still in the queue and the user isn't actually saved in the database. Second option using lambda DLQ is not possible because DLQ is only available with **asynchronous** invocation while cognito invokes lambda **synchronously**.

Comment: What I could think of right now is to use SQS with a `Post confirmation` trigger together with a `Pre sign-in` trigger which first checks if the user exists in the database, if not then deny the sign in request, that way the sign in request can only succeed when the message in the queue is finally processed.

Comment: I really like the idea of treating Cognito like any other OAuth provider (e.g. Google, Facebook) in that I just use it to get an auth token and a list of claims, everything else I manage in my app's DB.

Comment: While Cognito has the ability to trigger a "post confirmation Lambda" after a user is created, it does not have the ability currently to trigger a Lambda when a user is deleted, so I have a post confirmation Lambda creating the user in my app DB's user table but deleting will be more-complicated... I haven't figured out just how I am going to deal with that yet.

Answer (score 9):

You can certainly use Cognito User Pools service to manage authentication instead of your 'user' table, but not necessarily. You can also integrate other identity providers and login with Twitter, Amazon, etc, or even your own database. A benefit of using Cognito User Pools is that you don't have to code the authentication flows, as they are implemented by the service correctly and securely.

Best of luck with the code and the baby!